# Selenium unable to open URL on AWS Windows EC2 Instance

Tags: c#, windows, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a console application using Selenium and Chrome Driver which is working fine on my local machine Windows 7

Now when I am deploying the same to my AWS Windows Instance it is not working at all.
None of the websites are getting opened up in chrome browser.

Is there anything specific that one needs to do on AWS Windows EC2 instance.
Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Are you able to see the website on the EC2 instance without using Selenium? Is it working if you simply browse to the public IP/URL you have configured?

Comment: No it's not working in normal browser itself inside ec2 instance. So I don't know what's wrong here

Comment: Actually some sites like Google are opening but the ones which I am trying to work on are not opening in ec2 instance chrome browser

Comment: I would therefore suggest reviewing your website/instance configuration. It sounds like your internet gateway is working, but nothing else. Until you can see the website from your local machine, it will not be accessible by selenium